# Is it possible to specify a foreign key for a table field in Django models.py to any table from the database?

Tags: python, django

Suppose there is a table in the database "table", not created by Django. Is it possible to specify it as a foreign key in any way?

```py
class Object(models.Model):
    object_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    param = models.ForeignKey('table', on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
...
```

Comment: That is a `GenericForeignKey`, but this has a *lot* of disadvantages.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem . Is it better to do the ETL-process entirely in Django? Does not seem to be the best solution if you need to do UPDATE and UPSERT

Comment: GFK's answer the question posed in the title, but the body of the question is actually asking about the managed meta attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a meta option on Django models to specify that the table exists but is not managed by Django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#managed

Django can also build the model classes by pointing to the tables using the inspectdb manage command:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/legacy-databases/

So effectively you'd have:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    unmanaged_fk = models.ForeignKey('UnmanagedObject', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class UnmanagedObject(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table = 'Name_Of_My_Database_Table'
```